# MySQLI fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having a small issue with the following

```
public function getSiteName() {

    $query = "SELECT name FROM siteinfo";
    $result = $this->con->query($query);

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["name"]);
  }
```

I do NOT get an error when connecting to the database however I get the following

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /Users/russellharrower/Sites/evocca/etrading/system/core.php on line 15
```

I am wondering why would it not work? I used http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

The engine am using is **InnoDB**

Comment: $result will return a mysqli_result object when it succeeds, but returns FALSE on failure. Check with `if (!$result) die($this->con->error);`.

Comment: Your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27731077/ contains `if (!$conn->connect_errno) {
      $this->connected = true;` so you sure you got your parameters right? Where you may have meant to do `$result = $this->conn` or `$result = $this->connected`? Your query is obviously failing.

Comment: Do error checking. Something like `if(!$result) ... `

Comment: I doubt do you have a connection like .. 

`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");`
and are you trying to use:
`$result = $this->con->query($query);` ..?

Then I think you are missing `$con`, instead you have `con`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try something like this:

Taken from: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
        }

        /* free result set */
        $result->free();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: The issue with this is it would require me to create a .php file for every page, I want a core function like core.php

Comment: @RussellHarrower Do you mind updating your answer with what you're actually trying to do with the fetch?

Answer (score 0):

So After an hour of debugging I had to do the following.

For my project I am using a config.php as where I put all my Database connection defines.

*config.php*

```
<?php
define('DBServer','localhost'); // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
define('DBUser','root');
define('DBPass','PASSWORD');
define('DBName','ET5');
?>
```

*core.php*

```
<?php
class sys
{
  protected $con;

  public function __construct($con) {
    $this->con = $con;
  }

  public function getSiteName() {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM siteinfo";
    $result = $this->con->query($query);
    $res = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $res[] = $row['name'];
    }
    return $res;
  }
}
?>
```

*Index.php*

```
<?php
require_once("system/config.php");
require_once("system/core.php");
global $con ;
$con = new mysqli(DBServer, DBUser, DBPass, DBName);
if ($con->connect_errno)
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sys = new sys($con);
$result = $sys->getSiteName();
print_r($result);
?>
```